# MySQL WorkBench - Failed to Connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, mysql-workbench

I'm doing a college final year project using Spring. I was using Ubuntu 13.10 with STS and MySQL Workbench to manage the database. However, I had to move to a Windows machine as Ubuntu decided that it didn't like my trackpad or connecting to wireless anymore.

I have all other things set up but I get the attached error when trying to create an SQL connection in the Workbench. It works fine on Ubuntu, same software.

Any ideas?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYIKn.jpg

Comment: Are you running the MySQL service on your Windows machine?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I just installed the workbench. I assume that should set it up.

Comment: The workbench is a MySQL client, it's not the server that runs the database.

Comment: Cheers. I seem to have it. I was trying to install this but it kept saying something about converting to commercial license as there was stuff installed (which there may be as it's a college machine)

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Installed through MySQL installer and it seems to have sorted it.